# PNG image link not opening in IE11 browser for Jenkins report

Tags: jenkins, png, internet-explorer-11

I came across dozens of pages and came to post a new question on this topic as I could not find the answers.

I have a `Jenkins` server running in a remote machine in the network and I access the  application in my local machine to check the reports. The report is a `html` page and it has hyperlinks for screenshots (PNG file) and other html pages to analyze.

The problem is, when I use `Internet Explorer 11` to view this Jenkins report from my local machine, I am not able to open the screenshots or link to other html pages from the main report. When I use `Mozilla firefox` the links and images opens fine.

More annoyingly, if I trigger the report from my local `Eclipse` Workspace directly, I am able to open the report from the Repository folder in `IE11` itself with no issues.

Things I have did already with my browser and some of the information reg the report are mentioned below.

1. The Jenkins URL is added in the Trusted sites and pop ups are allowed in my local machine browser.
2. When I copy paste the URL for image hyperlink in the IE11, it opens the image properly.
3. In Internet options -> Advanced -> Multimedia, Show Pictures option is enabled.
4. `Enable Protected Mode` is disabled for all the zones.
5. `Compatibility view settings` changes did not have any impact on the issue.
6. In the Developer Tools `Emulation`, changing the Document mode did not have any impact on the issue.

The `head` tag in the Report html is specified below

```
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> 
</head>
```

What could be the problem root cause for the issue I am facing?

Comment: For testing purpose, try to set all your security zones with similar settings. Try to enable 'Navigate Windows and frames across different domain' and 'Access data sources across domains' option from Internet options->security tab-> custom level->Miscellaneous security settings. Than make a test and let us know about the result.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, the Security settings are kept at Medium to (Medium-Low) as per restrictions in the office. I have updated Misc settings like you told but the issue still persists.

Comment: Does t giving any error or warning message? If yes than let us know about that may help to identify the cause for the issue.

Comment: I even unchecked "Disable script debugging" to see if any error comes. But nothing happens once I click the link.

Comment: In that case, you can try to use fiddler tool and try to check whether it shows you information about any problem while you click the link on the page from IE may help to get some idea about the issue.